# If I’m trying to run the same script in ten different directories in a row, will this way work and is there a more concise command sequence?

Tags: command-line

Sorry if this is noobish, I had to pick up Ubuntu for a job and am not super well-versed in the intricacies of input and output yet. Basically, I’ve got a bunch of directories that each have a copy of the same script, and ordinarily I’d have to go into each directory, ./ each script separately, wait like two minutes and type “2” to select an option partway through the script, then back out and go to the next folder. One of the guys I’m working with said I could use the cat command and a pipe to type what I want to put into the script automatically rather than sitting and waiting for the prompt, but he didn’t show me how. Since I have ten of them, I was thinking I should be doing basically the following:

```
for i in $(ls -d [each of the folders]);
    do 
       cd $i;
       echo “2” > input.txt; 
       cat input.txt | ./scriptname.sh;
       rm input.txt;
       cd ..;
    done
```

So my questions are 1. Will/should this even work and 2. Is there a less clunky way to accomplish this?

Comment: In which directory does "input.txt" reside? Where is "scriptname.sh"? According to your code, both must reside in the directory $i.

Comment: @glenn We could eliminate the use of `input.txt` by writing `echo "2" | ./scriptname.sh`. But yes, `scriptname.sh` should be in the directories or in the $PATH.

Comment: Sorry, my working was unclear: there is "scriptname.sh" in **each** of the folders? So it's not the "same script" at all?

Comment: and I missed where you create the input.txt file. Note that you're using "curly quotes" (`“2”` as opposed to `"2"`), so that file will contain 4 characters (fancy quote, digit 2, fancy quote, newline) -- is the script prepared to handle that?

Comment: If `scriptname.sh` file is **exactly** identical in all the folders, the only reason it has been copied to all the folders is because it expects other input file(s) to be in the same folder it is in. If you can remove this limitation, then you can use just one copy of `scriptname.sh` on all the folders. It may be useful to hardcode the "2" in the `scriptname.sh` and put the loop inside the script.

Comment: Glenn, it has curly quotes because my iPhone keyboard puts those down instead of " marks if I don’t deliberately write them like that, so that’s just my mistake on here. My understanding was that by using echo and then some text inside the non-fancy quotes followed by a filename, I could create a new file with said name containing the text in the quotes while I’m in each of the ten separate directories, use that to feed a 2 and a newline into the script (which is all I would do if I were running it manually), and then delete input.txt to stay organized.

Comment: user68186 and Glenn again, scriptname.sh is completely identical in each of the ten directories but uses input files that aren’t the same in each directory. I thought about just editing scriptname.sh to automatically select the option I want, but I apparently can’t because it’s part of a larger procedure that was originally made by a long-since-graduated PhD student, and as an undergrad, I’m not allowed to mess with it. An earlier script in the process puts scriptname.sh in each directory by copying it from somewhere I don’t think I even have access to.

Answer (score 5):

Some notes:

1. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Assuming you want to use *all* the directories in the current folder, so

   ```
   for dir in */        # note the trailing slash
   ```

   IMO "dir" is a better varname than "i".
2. if not every directory is wanted, you can spell them out

   ```
   for dir in dir1 dir2 dir4 ...; do ...
   ```

   or use a glob pattern that will match the wanted dirs

   ```
   for dir in dir[1-46-9] ...; do ...
   ```

   or use an array to hold them, and iterate over the array

   ```
   dirs=(dirA dirB dirE dirG)
   for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do ...      # those quotes are required.
   ```
3. [Quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
4. This pattern is fine: `cd dir; do stuff ...; cd ..`.
   You could also create a subshell so the effects of `cd` vanish when the subshell exits.
5. It's conceivable that `cd` fails.

So, here's a slight alternate take

```
for dir in */; do
    ( cd "$dir" && echo 2 | ./scriptname.sh )
done
```

Comment: Nice! (That's all I wanted to say.)

Comment: If you want all directories in the current folder with the letters "methyl" in it, you can use `shopt -s globstar` and then `for dir in *methyle*/ ; do`, or something similar. I have not tested this.

Comment: I’m unfortunately not always doing it for every single directory in the current folder because sometimes one of them gets a step or two behind the others (can explain that in more detail if anyone cares but I’m occasionally not doing the exact same thing for all 10 is my point). But for the times when they’re all on the same step I’ll start doing what you said. What do you mean by cd failing?

Comment: If the directory resides on a remote filesystem and access is unavailable, cd can fail. It's unlikely to happen but IMO a good habit to get into.

Comment: Added a note about not using `*/`

Comment: Also, regarding the not parsing ls thing, I’ll certainly stop doing it, but am I interpreting your link correctly in thinking that it wouldn’t be an issue as long as I didn’t use any weird, potentially functional characters in filenames?